# Enviar e-mail para a minha conta c#

Tags: c#

Na criação do meu programa, coloquei uma Form para que o utilizar possa "Reportar Erro/Sugestões". Nessa forma coloquei 2 *textbox* e 1 *button*. 1 *textbox* para *Subject*, e a outra para que se possa escrever o que queira (mensagem).
O `button` serve para enviar esses dados para o meu e-mail. O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
    if (!(txtpara.Text.Trim() == ""))
        {
            To = txtpara.Text;
            Subject = txtassunto.Text;
            Body = txtmensagem.Text;

            mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(this.To));
            mail.From = new MailAddress("omeuemail@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = Subject;
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
            using (client)
            {
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("omeuemail@gmail.com", "aminhapassword");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(mail);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("E-Mail enviado com Sucesso!", "Sucesso");
        }
```

O erro é em:

> "client.Send(mail);", e diz: "Falha ao enviar e-mail" - SmtpException.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO pt. Por favor, leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Você não informou o que já fez até agora, quais são suas dúvidas específicas ou problemas que está tendo.

Comment: Editado amigo @Molx.

Comment: @GodfatherSantanta, você descreveu o problema melhor, mas vou insistir um pouco. Você precisa ser mais claro. Se não tem ideia de por onde começar, talvez o ideal seja procurar tutoriais do tipo [Como enviar email com código em C#?](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Como+enviar+email+com+c%C3%B3digo+em+C%23%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=dIooVd7vH4fbsASotoCoCg). No SO, procuramos responder perguntas mais específicas. Por exemplo, se você estiver um código pronto, mas que não funciona, poderia postar a parte importante para alguém dar uma olhada.

Comment: Caro @Molx, isso foi o que eu já fiz, porém, no momento do "client.Send(message)", dá-me sempre erro. Já tentei vários métodos sem sucesso...

Comment: Poderia colocar mais informações sobre o seu servidor smtp? As vezes o problema é justamente ele não estar ligado ou algo assim... Ainda, se puder detalhar melhor a exceção de SMTP que ele está lançando, já ajuda também.

Comment: Oi @FelipeAvelar, como assim mais informação sobre o meu servidor smtp? Tenho que fazer algo na minha conta gmail?

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente a porta do `SMTP` que você está usando está incorreta, sei que é possível utilizar a 25, a 465 e a 587, mas só obtive sucesso usando a 587.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient();
Smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
Smtp.Timeout = 300000;
Smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
Smtp.Port = 587;
Smtp.EnableSsl = true;
Smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");
Smtp.Send(Mensagem);
```

Esse é um código rodando em produção para envio de e-mail, utilizando uma conta do gmail.

@Edit para comentários:
Para capturar o texto da Exception, adicione essa linha no lugar da ultima:

```
try{
    Smtp.Send(Mensagem);
} catch( Exception ex) { 
    string s = ex.ToString(); //Tratar a exceção
}
```

Lembrando que essa implementação do try/catch é apenas para recebermos dados da tua exceção, não é recomendado tratar exceções dessa forma.

Comment: Oi @Marciano.Andrade, dá-me erro em "Smtp.Send(Mensagem);".

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Tem como tu colar todo o texto da `Exception` aqui? Não só o resultado da `.Message`, mas sim do `.ToString()` da `Exception`.

Comment: Como assim amigo? Não tem nenhum texto... @Marciano.Andrade

Comment: @GodfatherSantana dá uma olhada na edição da minha resposta, ali te mostro como pegar o valor que eu quero. Gostaria que colasse aqui o valor que a `string s` receber

Comment: O problema manteve-se amigo @Marciano.Andrade...

Comment: Sugestão, uma forma rápida de capturar excepcoes sem ter de interromper a execução do programa `Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)`. A mensagem aparece na janela de `Output` do VS. (Também e capaz de ser útil imprimir o *stack trace* da excepcao)

Comment: então @GodfatherSantana, preciso que você capture todo o stack trace da exceção, para isso você precisa colocar um breakpoint dentro do catch que eu alterei na minha resposta e me passar o valor que vai estar dentro da `string s`, ou então utilizar o método do omni, mas sem a stack trace vai ficar difícil te ajudar, até a tua rede pode estar bloqueando esse código de funcionar.

Comment: @GodfatherSantana, você tambem pode serializar a excessão como JSON e colar a mesma aqui, segue um exemplo de como serializar uma Excessão usando o Nuget `Newtonsoft Json`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wAKnL4

Comment: @TobyMosque, colei o código aí, mas não percebi nada... É só erros!